# Failing RefreshControl with ListView in iOS

Tags: ios, listview, react-native, pull-to-refresh

In my React Native (ver 0.23.0) project (Android + iOS) I want to use pull to refresh gesture to refresh the `ListView`.

This is my code:

```
<RefreshControl
  style={styles.container}
  refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
  onRefresh={this.onRefreshList} >
  <ListView
    onEndReachedThreshold={500}
    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderItem}
    pageSize={Const.defaultPerPage}
    scrollRenderAheadDistance={500}
    style={styles.container}
    renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
  />
</RefreshControl>
```

**It is working well on android but on ios I am getting this error:**

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong, because I am not iOS developer. Does anybody have? Or does anybody know any good alternative npm package to use for pull to refresh `ListView` for both platforms?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html), `RefreshControl` should be passed to the `ListView` as a prop, instead of wrapping the ListView in one:

```
<ListView
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
    />
  }
/>
```

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472865/refreshcontrol-in-listview-does-not-work-for-some-unknown-reason). Any help will be much appreciated!